# Sharepoint online 'Unsupported app only token.'

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I got myself a bearer token by calling `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` with the scope `https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/.default`

It's a token for a registered app in Azure AD.

When I use that token to make an API call like `https://infoinnobake.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:SP.Webb'&selectproperties='Title,Path'&rowlimit=500`
I only reveice `401 Unsupported app only token.`

can some explain why? Is it possible to access the sharepoint online API with an registered App on Azure AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this guide right here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

you need to create a certificate and upload the certificate to the registered app. Than you can use the API or the SharepointClient in various programming languages

Comment: I uploaded the self-signed certificate in Azure AD for my registered app. I am still getting the same error while trying Sharepoint API from the postman. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue (with slightly different error message: '*Token type is not allowed*') when using app-only, `ClientID` / `ClientSecret` based authentication in a tenant, that was recently created. In our old tenant (created in 2013) we could use the same authentication method without any problem. As it turned out, new tenants have a standard setting in `DisableCustomAppAuthentication` property, that disable this kind of auth., however it can be overriden using this command:

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

Source:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/sharepoint-online-authorization-issue-token-type-is-not-allowed

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286693/getting-invalid-request-token-type-is-not-allowed-error-while-accessing-lists

Furthermore:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

> Azure Access Control (ACS), a service of Azure Active Directory (Azure
> AD), has been retired on November 7, 2018. This retirement does not
> impact the SharePoint Add-in model, which uses the
> https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net hostname (which is not
> impacted by this retirement). For more information, see Impact of
> Azure Access Control retirement for SharePoint Add-ins. **For new
> tenants, apps using an ACS app-only access token is disabled by
> default.** We recommend using the Azure AD app-only model which is
> modern and more secure. **But you can change the behavior by running
> ‘set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false'** (needs the
> latest SharePoint admin PowerShell).

More details:

https://www.koskila.net/literally-breaking-changes-to-app-authentication-on-sharepoint-%F0%9F%98%B5

Comment: That is just wild to me that you can create a client secret, use the oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint to get a BEARER token, and then when you try to use it the error message just says '.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' without telling you that app only access token is disabled by default. How do they get away with this stuff?