# "Unsupported app only token" SharePoint API error even after adding certificate

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I am trying to use lists SharePoint API `https://xx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists` I am getting "Unsupported app only token" error when I try to access above API. I have referred to the documentation referred in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526581/sharepoint-online-unsupported-app-only-token) answer. I have added certificate on the registered app as well but still I am getting the same error. I am fetching SharePoint token as

URL "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"

Body

1. "grant_type" -> "client_credentials"
2. "scope" -> "https://xx.sharepoint.com/.default"
3. client_id -> client id of the app
4. client_secret -> client secret of the app

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to check any of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

I have met this error before. In fact, appid+ app secret authorization flow is not supported in app-only scenario. Even though either by using the client id and client secret of your application or by using the client id and a certificate will give you a **valid** access token. However only the access token obtained using a certificate is allowed to be used with SharePoint Online. If you try to use an app-only access token obtained using client id and client secret, SharePoint Online will return the following error:

> **Unsupported app only token.**

If you want to get authorized in Daemon app, you may need to turn to "appid + certificate" as @allen wu [suggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#using-this-principal-in-your-application-using-the-sharepoint-pnp-sites-core-library).

Below is the behind authorization process:

- [Second case: Access token request with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate)

BR

Answer (score 1):

It is not how certificate credentials work. This form of credential that an application can use for authentication is a JSON Web Token(JWT) assertion signed with a certificate that the application owns. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials).

So you cannot use client secret to get the access token.

You need [set up an Azure AD app for app-only access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#setting-up-an-azure-ad-app-for-app-only-access) at first.
Please refer to the samples from [Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#using-this-principal-with-pnp-powershell).

```
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using System;

namespace AzureADCertAuth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo";
            using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "<application id>", "contoso.onmicrosoft.com", @"C:\BertOnlineAzureADAppOnly.pfx", "<password>"))
            {
                cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And here are [sample projects](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) in GitHub.